# Match last occurance of a character in a string only if it appears multiple times in that string

Tags: regex, regedit

I want to use RegEx to do what the title sais.
So lets make a quick example: let's say we want to remove filename extentions (including the dot character) but only for files that have a dot character in their name. Given this example list:

```
this-is-a-filename-we-dont-change.doc
this.is.a.filename.we-will-change.doc
this_is_a_filename_we_dont_change.doc
```

since the second file has one (or more) dots in it's filename we want to have a match on `.doc` for that line only.

I started off with something simple like `.[^.$]*$` but that has two problems:

1. it will wrap the line if we have blank lines
2. it will also match the other filenames and not only the second one

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with a negated character class:

```
\.[^.\n]*\K\.[^.\n]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G9Xao2/3)

`[^.\n]` will match a character that is not dot and not newline.

`\K` is used for resetting matched information in PCRE.

Comment: Thanks but that was not the question. Only the '.doc' part in line 2 should match because it contains multiple dots.

Comment: oh sorry I misread. you can use `^.*\.[^.\n]*(\.[^.\n]+)$` (will update answer)

Comment: That now will match the hole line while I was trying to match only the '.doc' part of that second line. How can I match only that group?

Comment: Huh. Yes. Now I only have to find a way to use the captured group in Notepad++

Comment: Try this regex in Notepad++:`\.[^.\n]*\K\.[^.\n]+$`

Comment: Worked like a charm!